# Trying to use threads to save a file in the background

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine

So I am trying to use threads to save a file in the background to prevent the main unity thread from freezing until the file is saved:

```
public void SaveMap() {
  MapRendererBehaviour mapRendererBehaviour = GameObject.FindWithTag("MapRenderer").GetComponent<MapRendererBehaviour>();
  SerializedMap serializedMap = mapRendererBehaviour.ToSerializedData();

  Debug.Log("test");
  _saveMapThread = new Thread(() => {
    string saveMapJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(serializedMap);

    File.WriteAllText(_saveMapFilePath, saveMapJson);
  });
}
```

For some reason the thread code does not seem to be executing because the file is not getting saved. If I comment out the thread creation and just leave the body of the thread in there, the file saves properly.

Anyone know what I might be doing wrong here (I assume I am doing something dumb as I have never tried to use threads before).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might be a shot in the dark but if you are using named threads instead of tasks you normally have to say ThreadName.Start() after so for example after declaring the thread say:

```
_saveMapThread.Start();
```

Comment: Can you use Tasks with unity? `Task.Run(...)` may be a little safer?

Comment: Good point axlj however I don't think you can by the looks of this post - http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/357033/unity3d-and-c-coroutines-vs-threading.html

Comment: Time to upgrade! http://www.stevevermeulen.com/index.php/2017/09/23/using-async-await-in-unity3d-2017/ :-)

Comment: Very true! Seems the latest version has some good new features.

Comment: Calling `.Start()` (which was not in both thread example I looked up) did fix my issue.

Comment: Also I did try using async / await but that did not work with Unity 2017.1.1 (can't use the beta version because of other libraries I am using).

Comment: That's fair enough. Glad that it helped!