# Fast way to save 2D array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, unity-game-engine, save

I am trying to save a 2D array during a game in Unity. I tried to save the array to csv using using StreamWriter, and while this works, it is too slow and the game stops/crashes for a second. Is there a faster way to save the array? It does not need to be to csv, as long as I can later retrieve the array in C# I can make the conversion post-game.

Edit - More information:  I am using Leap Motion to track the user's hands. I would like to save position and rotation of each hand bone (palm + 3 bones per finger) at each frame.

Comment: Does it need to be saved *during* game play? Can it be stored in memory and saved after the time-critical portion of the game is completed?

Comment: We will do that as a last resort. This is for research, we are trying to save data throughout the game so that we do not lose it if anything crashes.

Comment: I would recommend looking into event sourcing. If you treat state as an event stream of changes you will only need to append to a file. There are concepts of snapshots etc to speed up state restoration.

Comment: I am  new to this, so I just started reading about event sourcing since you posted. I think this may not apply, but I would appreciate your feedback about it!  I am using Leap Motion to track the user's hands. I would like to save position and rotation of each hand bone (palm + 3 bones per finger) at each frame. Do you think this technique could still be used?

Comment: If the 2D array is large (takes of a lot of memory), you could also look into persisted [memory-mapped files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile?view=netcore-3.1).  If you open a memory-mapped file that persists to the disk, you can manipulate its data at virtual memory speeds, but the data will live on disk in the end.  If you can, reducing the size of what you save to disk (as @Jason gets at) is probably better.

Comment: Since you're wanting to save every frame, maybe store the current state of the array into a queue, and have a background process not tied to your UI thread which writes the states to the file.

Comment: BinaryFormatter is ultra fast if you saving an array already, yet its not something secure on client side anymore

Answer (score 0):

For Unity 2017 and later, you can try saving the data in a different thread. However, since you will do it every frame, you also need to implement a queuing system to prevent `frame x+n` saved before `frame x` if saving of `frame x` lags.

You can check these resources as a start:

- [Trying to use threads to save a file in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596930/trying-to-use-threads-to-save-a-file-in-the-background)
- http://www.stevevermeulen.com/index.php/2017/09/using-async-await-in-unity3d-2017/